# GCC branches vs Subversion and Git

Tags: git, svn, gcc, github, gnu

At this address you can find the `svn` branches of the `gcc` project

```
https://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/
```

now [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GitMirror) it says that there are even 3 "mirrors" of the `svn` repository hosted on gnu.org, repo.or.cz and github, the problem is that :

- if you compare just this 3 `git` repositories they look like they contain the same codebase ( branches, heads and tags ) but the content doesn't even looks like it's compatible with the original `svn` repository, they are just hosting different projects, different branches .
- some branches in the `git` repositories are old, I found repositories where the last commit was about 1 year old, and in general they look like they have almost nothing to do with the latest developments from the `gcc` projects .

Unfortunately I see that the `gcc` project doesn't publish snapshots for the latest changes in those branches, not even with a weekly cycle, and `subversion` is giving me a lot of headaches lately, so I would like to use `git` .

The problem is, considering that I'm interested in 1 of the branches listed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/), How I can reach the equivalent `git` repository ? Where is the official `git` repository for the gcc branches ?

Comment: If the svn repository is the most up-to-date, would using `git svn` to check it out be a possibility?

Comment: @orbrey well that could be an option, but it's still not a git repository, it's a "fix" on the client side, not on the server side . Also I would like to take the opportunity to know why there is such organization in the svn and git repositories, but probably they just dropped the git ones .

Answer (score -1):

From GitMirror page

> There is a read-only git mirror of the gcc svn repository available
>   at:
>
> git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git
>   https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git
>   git+ssh://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git

I.e gcc.gnu.org's Git-repo is 1-st level (fastest in sync) mirror of full SVN-source

> the content doesn't even looks like it's compatible with the original svn repository

RLLY? I tried to use web-interface to [SVN](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/) and [Git](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=summary) from gcc.gnu.org and see in log only short delay for last commit (commit from 41 min ago already mirrorred, commit with 6 minutes age - no yet)

> considering that I'm interested in 1 of the branches

Just clone with `git svn` this single branch from original SVN-repository and eliminate one additional layer and point of (possible) failure on|in external Git-mirror

Comment: if you say so, could you please post the link of the `git` repository of the `gomp-4_0-branch` or any branch in the `google` subdirectory ? What you just checked ? The 2 are just not the same thing, they even have different names .

Comment: @user2485710 - **every** Git mirror holds **all** SVN-branches, there are not *default* mirror-per-branch repositories from GCC team

Comment: ok, those are svn-branches, where are the corresponding url/branches for git ? there are no dedicated repository nor branches, they are just not there .

Comment: @user2485710 - I'm too lazy to clone Git-repo locally, but https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GitMirror says clearly "Our clone contains all the gcc branches. List the available branches: `git branch -a`" and https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GitMirror#Getting_started_-_Read-Only recommends `git config --add remote.origin.fetch 'refs/remotes/*:refs/remotes/svn/*'` **before fetch**

Comment: I did `git ls-remote --heads --tags --refs git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git` just to check tags/heads/refs all at once, nothing, what you are saying can't be proven right. the command `git config --add remote.origin.fetch 'refs/remotes/*:refs/remotes/svn/*'` it's not even for a `git` repository, if you read carefully enough you can see that it's for the `svn` repository .

Comment: @LazyBadger Even today, the svn and git repositories don't have the same branches; there are missing ones and extra ones in both directions.